# List of PDOStatement::bindParam data_type parameters

Tags: php, pdo

Is there a list describing all of the data_type parameters you can use in `PDOStatement::bindParam()` ? If none, what do you commonly use, and for what type of field ?

According to PHP manual: *data_type* Explicit data type for the parameter using the PDO::PARAM_* constants.

I know about the `PDO::PARAM_INT` and `PDO::PARAM_STR` . I've heard of `PDO::PARAM_LOB` but I wasn't sure how and when to use that, though. (for date ?)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the documentation [here](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php):

> ```
> PDO::PARAM_BOOL (integer)
> Represents a boolean data type.
> PDO::PARAM_NULL (integer)
> Represents the SQL NULL data type.
> PDO::PARAM_INT (integer)
> Represents the SQL INTEGER data type.
> PDO::PARAM_STR (integer)
> Represents the SQL CHAR, VARCHAR, or other string data type.
> PDO::PARAM_LOB (integer)
> Represents the SQL large object data type.
> PDO::PARAM_STMT (integer)
> Represents a recordset type. Not currently supported by any drivers.
> PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT (integer)
> Specifies that the parameter is an INOUT parameter for a stored procedure. You must bitwise-OR this value with an explicit PDO::PARAM_* data type.
> ```

Comment: yes, my bad, I missed out the section there. Should've search for PDO constants instead of PDO statement bindParam(). Thank you very much tomhaigh.

Comment: Is `PARAM_INT` the one to use for `text` datatypes? Say 1000 characters.

Comment: How about decimals and floats? Is there anyway to not convert them to strings, but keep the decimal values?

Comment: Should I use a BOOL or an INT for a BIT type?